# How to enumerate all icons on desktop

Tags: c++, windows

I want to enumerate all icons on desktop in c++.The answer to a similar question is using IShellFolder::EnumObjects,but That's not the answer I need.It will enumerate some that are not actually displayed on the desktop.It need support Windows XP.

```
HRESULT BindToCsidl(int csidl, REFIID riid, void **ppv) {
  HRESULT hr;
  PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl;
  hr = SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(NULL, csidl, &pidl);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    IShellFolder *psfDesktop;
    hr = SHGetDesktopFolder(&psfDesktop);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      if (pidl->mkid.cb) {
        hr = psfDesktop->BindToObject(pidl, NULL, riid, ppv);
      } else {
        hr = psfDesktop->QueryInterface(riid, ppv);
      }
      psfDesktop->Release();
    }
    CoTaskMemFree(pidl);
  }
  return hr;
}

void enum_dekstop() {
  HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
  if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
    IShellFolder2 *psfDesktop;
    hr = BindToCsidl(CSIDL_DESKTOP, IID_PPV_ARGS(&psfDesktop));
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
      IEnumIDList *peidl;
      hr = psfDesktop->EnumObjects(NULL, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS, &peidl);
      if (hr == S_OK) {
        PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidlItem;
        while (NOERROR == peidl->Next(1, &pidlItem, NULL)) {
          STRRET display_name = {0};
          HRESULT hr = psfDesktop->GetDisplayNameOf(pidlItem, SIGDN_NORMALDISPLAY, &display_name);
          CoTaskMemFree(pidlItem);
        }
      }
      psfDesktop->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();
  }
}
```

Comment: What answer? Also, could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58925889/edit) and show us what code you have so far?

Comment: The question has been re-edited